# How can I monitor CPU usage in AWS SageMaker while in a notebook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

It doesn't seem that there is a way to monitor the usage of resources while in a Jupyter Notebook. Normally I can see what percentage of my cpu I am using. This might just be installing jupyter-resource-usage but I haven't been able to resolve that package in a notebook without issues.

Comment: How about using Cloudwatch? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatch.html

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch integration as suggested by Shimo is the AWS recommended approach.

Alternatively, you could use [SageMaker Studio Notebooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks.html) which provide [native resource utilization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-menu.html) without leaving the notebook. This is the simplest approach without any additional configuration.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn’t know studio had this. Wish there were an real time instance solution as well, but haven’t been able to find one.

Comment: No problem. AWS is really pushing SageMaker Studio, my guess is they will  eventually replace the standalone notebooks in the future.

Comment: I realise this is from a few years ago - I'm keen to show the CPU / MEM bars but I can't find them in Studio - possibly this has been removed, or am I missing how to show them? Can't see reference in the links provided unfortunately.